# Input string is not in correct format?

Tags: c#, streamreader

Ok, hey. I made a program for an in-game.. game. And I have it load data for a player from their own .txt on my computer. Whenever i try to command (.load) it tells me (at split[1] where it is converted to an int32) which is just a test to see if your bombs load, input string is not in correct format, heres the code:

```
StreamReader streemy = new StreamReader(@"c:\Usernames\" + player[m.GetInt(0)].username + ".txt");
string read = streemy.ReadToEnd();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(read))
{
   string[] split = read.Split('=');
   player[m.GetInt(0)].bombs = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
   Say(names[m.GetInt(0)].ToUpper() + ": You data has been loaded!");
   streemy.Close();
}
else
{
   Say(names[m.GetInt(0)].ToUpper() + ": Your data was empty :( Say '.save' to save your current data!");
}
```

.save Saves the data to the .txt, "names[m.GetInt(0)]" is their username, Say just tells them in the game the message. Thanks for your help! PS: player is a struct, which has ints like bombs.

Comment: So, what happens there is no '=' in your read string and you are trying to read the 1st position split[1] ??

Comment: what is the value of `split[1]`. Just take it into a string variable and check it whether it can be valid integer or not.

Comment: What are the values of `m.GetInt(0)` and `split[1]`?

Comment: It saves as b=<bombamount> so the split[1] should be "0" because right now there is no way to get bombs, just testing and it doesnt work.

Comment: m.GetInt(0) is the player's user ID

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So if the value is not valid integer then you can treat as 0 or *no bomb*.

```
int numberOfBombs = 0;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out numberOfBombs);
```

now *numberOfBombs* would retain the actual value if there is valid integer field present otherwise it will be 0.

Comment: Thanks :) But i found the error. I had the messagebox say what it said bombs were, and it gave 0 AND rs, which is supposed to be rifle shots. I forgot that it didn't separate, it saves like b=0 rs=0 ps=0 h=0 so, thanks though

Comment: Are you sure that there is no any other `=` presents before `b=0` in the text file?

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting a `FormatException`.
[FormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is thrown when the arguement is not in valid format.
I think that the value of split[1] is not a valid integer.
According to msdn.

> FormatException : value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).

Using the `ToInt32(string)` method is equivalent to passing value to the Int32.Parse(String) method. value is interpreted by using the formatting conventions of the [current thread culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
You can call the Int32.TryParse method instead. It returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.